# Show all attributes of Two Tables Using Inner Join - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a very basic SQL Question. I have three tables as shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE customers
(
CID                 int auto_increment,
Name                varchar (100),
Address             varchar (100),
Phone               char (10),
BooksOutstanding    int,
AcctBalance         numeric (8,2),
CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (CID)
);


CREATE TABLE books
(
ISBN        char(10),
Title       varchar (100),
Author      varchar (100),
Publisher   varchar (100),
Category    varchar (100),
LoanPeriod  int,
OverdueRate numeric (8,2),
CONSTRAINT books_pk PRIMARY KEY (ISBN)
);

CREATE TABLE borrows
(
CID     int,
ISBN    char (10),
CONSTRAINT borrows_PK PRIMARY KEY (CID, ISBN),
CONSTRAINT borrows_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (CID) references customers (CID),
CONSTRAINT borrows_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (ISBN) references books(ISBN)
);
```

I need to do an Inner Join for the customers and borrows table and show all attributes. I'm very confused by the "show all attributes" part of the question.
This is the code I used:

```
SELECT customers.CID
FROM customers
INNER JOIN borrows
ON customers.CID=borrows.CID;
```

What do I need to change to "show all attributes?"

Thanks in advance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation of the problem is very unclear but i assume you are looking for:

```
SELECT
   C.*, BK.*
FROM customers C
  JOIN borrows B
    ON C.CID = B.CID
  JOIN books BK
    ON B.ISBN = BK.ISBN
```

or you can use `LEFT JOIN` if you want to see `customers` who hasn't related books.